# How use custom-style or shared styles in polymer 3 preview

Tags: polymer-3.x

I need to use common styles for app, but `<custom-style>` doesn't work. Attribute `include` in `<style></style>` doesn't work also. How do it?

Comment: I've added a updated answer. See my alternative approach below to use template literals over `style include`

Answer (score 11):

*EDIT: Alternative approach, use template literals.*

I realized that there is, what I feel is a much better and more
natural alternative now that template literals is being used.

In `shared-styles.js`:

```
import { html } from @polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js;

export const sharedStyles = html`
    <style>
        ... various styles here ...
    </style>
`;
```

Now in the custom element file you want to use it ( `my-element.js` ):

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from @polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js;
import { sharedStyles } from './shared-styles.js';

class MyElement extends PolymerElement {

    ... element code ...

        get template() {
            return html`
                ${sharedStyles}
                <style>
                    ... your element custom styles here ...
                </style>
            `;
        }

    ... rest of your element code ...

}
```

For me this makes far more sense because we are using native javascript and
avoid any extra polyfills that may be required by the `include=""`
functionality.

I also think this is a bit more future proof, since the `include=""` syntax
isn't really in the spec and I don't expect it will be? (Can anyone correct me
if I'm wrong on that?)

*END (Alternative approach)*

*OLD Answer below*

This has now been documented in the upgrade guide when 3.0 went live.

See the first section under "Less common upgrade tasks" on this page:
https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/upgrade

Also, remember that you would need to import `custom-style` into the js module before it will work.
Should be located here: `polymer/lib/elements/custom-style.js`

Comment: Just noticed that my approach above is already being discussed in this thread here: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/4940

Answer (score 2):

Had the same Problem, solved it by doing it manually:

```
const documentContainer = document.createElement('div');
documentContainer.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');

documentContainer.innerHTML = `
  <dom-module id="shared-styles">
    <template>
      <style>...</style>
    </template>
  </dom-module>`;

document.head.appendChild(documentContainer);
```

Then you can use it by simply importing and including.

```
import './shared-styles.js';
...
static get template() {
    return `<style include="shared-styles"></style>...`;
}
```

I got this solution from the [polymer-modulizer](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-modulizer), but i hope there will be a better way in the future.

Comment: The polymer 3.0 upgrade guide now has a good example of how to do this. See my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If we follow what polymer team has done already, then you need **myapp-styles.js** as below

```
import {html} from '@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/html-tag.js';

/*
  custom classes for my application
*/

const template = html`
<dom-module id="myapp-styles">
  <template>
    <style>
      .bold{
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
`;
template.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
document.head.appendChild(template.content);
```

Then in the **component page** you need to **import 'myapp-styles.js';** and simply include it along with custom-style tag

```
<style is="custom-style" include="myapp-styles iron-flex iron-flex-alignment"></style>
```